# cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow' after pyinstaller

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to build an exe and this error showed up when I execute the exe.[image: error screenshot]

I use tensorflow in a virtual environment with Jupyter notebook.
I am a beginner. Sorry if I have made some silly mistakes.

Comment: Can you also, please, add the `pyinstaller` command you used? As far as I remember, you should use the `--onefile` flag.

Comment: Hi! I used pyinstaller -F ABT.py

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is explicitly telling `Python` what to bundle.
From the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search):

```
--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
    Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable. The path separator is platform specific, os.pathsep (which is ; on Windows and : on most unix systems) is used. This option can be used multiple times.

--add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
    Additional binary files to be added to the executable. See the --add-data option for more details. This option can be used multiple times.

-p DIR, --paths DIR
    A path to search for imports (like using PYTHONPATH). Multiple paths are allowed, separated by ‘:’, or use this option multiple times  

--hidden-import MODULENAME, --hiddenimport MODULENAME
    Name an import not visible in the code of the script(s). This option can be used multiple times.
```

Ask it to bundle the `pywrap_tensorflow` module.

```sh
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import pywrap_tensorflow ~/myproject/source/myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go for one-folder bundle approach then you can do the following:

You need to bundle *pywrap_tensorflow* with everything else. You need to make a change to the *.spec* file as follows.

```
a = Analysis(...
             binaries=[('add_location_of_pywrap_tensorflow_from_your_virtual_env_here','folder')],
             ...)
```

i.e. you need to mention the **path to pywrap_tensorflow** from your virtual environment and add a **folder** name where it will be stored in your bundled folder (*dist* folder).

Comment: Where do I look for to find the location?

Comment: it must be somewhere in your *venv* folder _./venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/_

Comment: I cannot find anything with the keyword "pywrap" in my whole Anaconda3 folder.